# How do I kill a process given its "command"?

Tags: process, kill

I have a process called "P1", right now the way I kill the process is:

```
$ ps aux | grep "P1"
" Now it returns two processes related to "P1": one is the actual P1 process I want to kill, the other one is the "grep P1" which I don't care.
$ kill -9 <P1 pid>
```

However, I wish to combine the two processes into one. Currently I couldn't find an efficient way to do that mainly because I have to look for the  from the output of the first command. Any good method?

Comment: Don't use "-9", that's a last resort option, not something to use routinely. `pkill -x P1` is the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pgrep` with the `-x` flag:

```
kill -9 $(pgrep -x P1)
```

or better, with `pkill` you can do this:

```
pkill -9 -x P1
```

with BSD `pkill`:

```
pkill 9 -x P1
```

Comment: I'm missing something. Does pkill not provide the exact match option (-x)?

Comment: @KalvinLee He wanted to use `-9`, at least my version doesn't have that option.

Comment: @DisplayName What OS are you on? I'm not aware of any `pkill` program that doesn't support a signal number option.

Comment: @Gilles Sorry, I messed up the syntax, It does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `killall(1)` (at least here on Fedora Linux). It has a raft of options.

Personally, I use it almost exclusively when I know that there is ***just one*** process with the given name.

Comment: Beware that unlike `pkill` which is quite consistent, `killall` has dramatically different implementations depending on the OS used, especially System V based ones like Solaris where it will do what its name says, kill all running processes (regardless of their names.)